# Proof that arithmetic mean of σ(n) & φ(n) is >=n

Tags: analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

I need help with a few problems of my Maths homework:

(1). Proof that arithmetic mean of $\sigma(n)$ and $\phi(n)$ is $\ge$ $n$.

(2). Proof that harmonic mean of $\sigma(n)$ and $\phi(n)$ is $\le$ $n$.

Mayank

Comment: You should tell us what you've tried. Although, you didn't say what $\varphi$ and $\sigma$ are.

Comment: You need not mention your name in the question. It is displayed everytime you post anything on this site as per your profile details.

Comment: Fun fact: _geometric_ mean of $\sigma(n)$ and $\varphi(n)$ is also $\le n$. An unexpected case of AM-GM, so to say.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the definitions of $\sigma$ and $\phi$: we have
$$
\sigma(n) = \sum_{d \vert n}{d},\quad
 \phi(n) = \prod_i{(p_i - 1) \cdot p_i^{e_i-1}}.
$$

Expand the product and rewrite it as
$ \phi(n) = \sum_{d \vert n}{a_d \cdot d}$
with coefficients $a_d \in \{-1,0,1\}$.  Then we have
$ \sigma(n) + \phi(n) = \sum_{d \vert n}{(a_d + 1) \cdot d} $,
and since $a_n = 1$:
$$
\sigma(n) + \phi(n) = 2 \cdot n + \sum_{d \vert n, d < n}{(a_d + 1) \cdot d} \ge 2n.
$$
This shows that the arithmetic mean is $\ge n$. A similar computation shows the second claim.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215261/find-all-positive-integers-n-such-that-phin-sigman-2n.

Comment: @Maurice Yes, thank you. This question here is almost a duplicate, but perhaps not exactly.